# Pest on Ponytail Palm (Beaucarnea Recurvata)

Tags: identification, diagnosis, plant-health, pests, palm

Today I discovered a pest on my Ponytail Palm.

I noticed that it has been getting dry leaves and losing them since 2 weeks ago.

I hope someone can help me to identify the pest and a possible solution for it.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Here are some photos:
[image: ponytail palm pest]

[image: ponytail palm pest]

[image: ponytail palm pest]

[image: ponytail palm pest]

[image: ponytail palm pest]

Answer (score 1):

These are probably mealybugs. Mealybugs don't move about much, just suck the sap, weaken the plant, and leave a sticky mess. Your population looks quite high so time to treat is very soon. Alcohol will get them. I think I would start with a small piece of cloth dipped in isopropyl alcohol wrapped around the leaf, start at the base of the leaf and pull towards you in one great swipe. Should be able to get the leaves cleaned in no time. Then look for an insecticidal soap for mealybugs and follow the instructions to get the small ones in cracks and crevices. Repeat as required to get them under control.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it helped me a lot.